# Localhost not working with vue.js

Tags: node.js, localhost

Im new using vue.js, so I just installed vue.cli and I tried localhost:8080 and it worked perfectly showing the vue welcome page. Then, 2 minutes later, localhost is not showing the page anymore (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED). I uninstalled vue and installed it again and it happens everytime, it works a few minutes and then it fails. What can be the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: "connection refused" means the service is not running. Check the log files. However, development environments are off topic here.